# The field 'State' contains the value 'Approved' that is not in the list of supported values

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am working with the Scrum workflow in TFS (Visual Studio 2017) and the only available value for the state is `New` when I would be expecting `Approved`, `Committed` and `Done`.

Why are they missing? How could I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The transitions between the different states of the work items are defined thanks to a specific workflow.

You have to save your work item with the "new" state before being able to modify its state to other states like Approved for example.

You can find more information at this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=vsts

Comment: Hello Patrice, I had already done before (save my work item with the "new" state). It's simply that the other states Approved, Committed and Done don't exist in the state drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have customized your WIT definition file (in you scenario it should be `Product Backlog Item.xml` file), and removed the state `Approved`, `Committed` and `Done` and transitions from the file.

So, you just need to add them back and set the transitions between the different states of the work items accordingly.

If you only customized the PBI wit definition file, then the simplest way is **exporting** the PBI wit definition file from a normal team project (with non-customized templated, it will have the state values you needed), then **import** the file to your current team project to apply the changes.

However if you also customized other things for your process template, then you may need to modify other related things based on your customized process template.

See [Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018) for details.

You can also use the extension [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) to export and import the wit file.